# Is it possible to combine digital signature to provide message addition?

Tags: rsa, public-key, elgamal-signature, cryptocurrency

Let's assume we are using the textbook RSA where $Sig(x)=x^d$. Alice has public key $(e,N)$, and private key $(d,p,q)$.

Now, if Alice sends $Sig(5)$ and $Sig(10)$ to Bob, where $5$ and $10$ is just numbers, is there a way to combine them on Bob's side to get $Sig(15)$?

If this is not possible in RSA, is it possible in other schemes like, for example, ElGamal) ?

Please note that I'm looking for a solution to handle this via *"addition"*, not *"multiplication"*.

Comment: It is likely meant $Sig(x)=x^d\bmod N$. Hint: Bob [or Carol impersonating Alice to Bob] knowing the public key, $Sig(5)$ and $Sig(10)$, can obtain $Sig(50$).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comments, it is easy to do with multiplication, however, I asking for addition.

Comment: _In theory_ you could be able to compute $Sig(15)$ just with multiplication (because the products wrap around $\bmod N$). However if you found an efficient algorithm to do that _I think_ you would have discovered an efficient way to turn textbook RSA into a fully homomorphic encryption scheme (as we are pretty sure that RSA isn't an efficient FHE scheme, it will be hard for you to find such an algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there another way to do it then (other than RSA)?

Comment: So you are actually asking for an additive-homomorphic signature scheme? I don't know any, but you may want to make this intent more clear in your question.

Comment: @Sari Related to your moderator flag asking how to "promote" this question and where to "buy" such points etc., please see our help center; more specifically *["What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)* as well as *["What is a bounty? How can I start one?"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)*. As you'll see you can't "buy" reputation points. Instead, you earn them (for free) by interacting with the website. It's all described in the [help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help). Hope that helps...

Comment: @SEJPM Intent seems to be explained by that [tag:digital-cash] tag... so, think crypto-currency (digital ledgers like blockchains et al). At least, that's what explains it to me (unless I'm misinterpreting something).

Comment: [This paper on homomorphic digital signatures](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/hom-rsa02.pdf) might be useful; It states that additively homomorphic signature schemes must be insecure.

Answer (score 6):

No, in textbook RSA signature with $\operatorname{Sig}(x)=x^d\bmod N$, there is no method to deduce $\operatorname{Sig}(15)$ from $\operatorname{Sig}(5)$ and $\operatorname{Sig}(10)$.

---

It is possible to deduce $\operatorname{Sig}(50)$, by using the general fact that in textbook RSA signature, if $x$ and $y$ are positive integers (with $xy$ below the limit for messages that can be signed, if any), then $\operatorname{Sig}(xy)\;=\;\operatorname{Sig}(x)\operatorname{Sig}(y)\bmod N$. But notice that being able to obtain an admissible signature for a message from the signature of other messages is considered a break of a signature scheme. That's why textbook RSA signature with $\operatorname{Sig}(x)=x^d\bmod N$ is not a secure signature scheme (rather, it is a building block towards one).

Further, if we have a signature scheme such that $\operatorname{Sig}(x+y)$ can be deduced from $\operatorname{Sig}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Sig}(y)$, then the signature of any message $x>0$ can be deduced from $\operatorname{Sig}(1)$ with $O(\log(x))$ deductions. That's why the literature tends to consider such additively homomorphic signature schemes only to repel them.

---

If we really want an additively homomorphic signature scheme, we can define one related to RSA, as $\operatorname{Sig'}(x)=\operatorname{Sig}(g^x\bmod N)=(g^x\bmod N)^d\bmod N=(g^d\bmod N)^x\bmod N$ for some fixed public $g$ generator of the groups $\mathbb Z_p^*$ and $\mathbb Z_q^*$ (it is easier and best that $(p-1)/2$ and $(q-1)/2$ are primes). In order to verify the alleged signature $s$ of $x$ per this system, it is checked that $s$ is the textbook RSA signature for $g^x\bmod N$, that is $0\le s<N$ and $s^e\bmod N\,=\,g^x\bmod N$. For all non-zero $a$ and $b$ and messages $x$ and $y$ it holds that $\operatorname{Sig'}(ax+by)\;=\;\operatorname{Sig'}(x)^a\operatorname{Sig'}(y)^b\bmod N$. This is comes at the price of extreme insecurity: revealing the signature of $x$ and $y$ allows the efficient computation of the signature of any multiple of $\gcd(x,y)$.

Comment: You may want to note that as per your reasoning such a scheme at least violates the [UF-KMA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44210/23623) security definition.

Comment: To complete @SEJPM 's comment: For example, given the signature on message $1$, say $\sigma = \operatorname{Sig'}(1)$, the signature on any message $x$ can be obtained as $\operatorname{Sig'}(x) = \sigma^x \bmod N$.